# WordPress multisite Nginx - Error establishing database connection

Tags: wordpress, nginx, multisite

I'm setting up wordpress multisite on nginx system, with Top level domains, so i'm trying to get:

1. example1.com (main site)
2. example2.com

Both should redirect to the same root, and use different D/B.

```
wp config:

/* Multisite */
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);


define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', '' );
define( 'ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/' );
define( 'COOKIEPATH', '/' );
define( 'SITECOOKIEPATH', '/' );
```

and configured the following on sites-available:
example2.com

```
server {
        server_name  example2.com;
        return 302 $scheme://example1.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name example2.com www.example.2com
    root /home/domains/example1/public_html;
        index index.php;
    include global/restrictions.conf;
 #   include global/wordpress.conf;

}
```

First domain works fine,
On second domain i get "error establishing database connection".

Answer (score 0):

After making sure your multisite and DNS are properly configured, I would recommend using `wp db reset` on your cli and then reimporting your db. I've had all sorts of issues with multi sites where the db had a mind of its own upon import.